# Importing csv file removes "dot": 44.4 becomes 444

Tags: excel, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv file to Excel (Office 365), and in order for it to split it correctly I am using the delimiter comma. But doing this my data changes from 44.4 to 444. Note: I tried changing my decimal symbol to "." instead of my regional ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not super familiar with 365, but I will assume they import the same way as excel 2016.

Is your "text" separated with a qualifier? This will help separate your Completed Text items, and separate items. Normally `" "` are used as a qualifier.

Normally i see CSV files setup like this...`"Some_Text_Here", "1", "This_is_the_third_column"` Either way, check that you have your TEXT within a "qualifier."

Comment: My text does not have a qualifier. It is on the form:
1871-01-01,4.44,0.26,0.4,12.46,5.32,89.0,5.21,8.02, 

Is there a way to add a qualifier on all the data easily?

Comment: I tested different things manually. Apparently it works having a qualifier AND changing the data to 4,44 instead of 4.44 (even though I changed decimal symbol to ".")  - So guess I just need to change all . to , and then somehow add a qualifier to everything.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been on vacation.

You shouldn't have to replace the decimal point. Within excel, you can import based on data formatted like this....`"1871-01-01","4.44",<etc...>' Also make sure that you don't have multiple delimiters turned on. Excel's "Text" import function can have multiple options enabled for delimiters. (Again, not certain with excel 365 but I would assume very similar).